# JavaScript dynamic dropdown with different text and values form php json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have some trouble for editing some PHP and javascript (ajax) code.
What this does is to generate some html dropdown with the options from a json.

My problem is for the dropdown options values and texts, because they are the same (value==text):

```
<option value="value">text</option>
```

How do I edit the PHP part and the $main json array to have loc_id for the VALUE and location_title for the TEXT of pickuplocation.

PHP code:

```
$q_categ="select loc_id, location_title from bk_all_location";
$sth = $dbo->prepare($q_categ);
$sth->execute();
$pickuplocation = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); 

$main = array('pickuplocation'=>$pickuplocation, 'value'=>array("pickuplocation1"=>"$pickuplocation1"));
echo json_encode($main);
```

Then here in the javascript ajax have to edit to get different values for text and value.
For text, the value of columns location_title from mysql, and for value, the value of loc_id from mysql.

javascript code:

```
for (j = document.myForm.pickuplocation.options.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    document.myForm.pickuplocation.remove(j);
}
var pickuplocation1 = myObject.value.pickuplocation1;
for (i = 0; i < myObject.pickuplocation.length; i++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = myObject.pickuplocation[i];
    optn.value = myObject.pickuplocation[i];
    document.myForm.pickuplocation.options.add(optn);
    if (optn.value == pickuplocation1) {
        document.myForm.pickuplocation.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

I did simplify the code as most, to make is easy to understand. I need some hints for the PHP and ajax code... Meanwhile I will keep trying to find the solution.
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution:

in the PHP had to change to $pickuplocation = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
and in the javascript had to change:

```
optn.text = myObject.pickuplocation[i].location_title;
optn.value = myObject.pickuplocation[i].loc_id;
```

Thanks!